# How to programatically select ComboBox value within Cell Factory?

Tags: java, javafx

My `TableView` uses a custom `CellFactory` to display a `ComboBox` in one column, allowing the user to select from available options. Those options are loaded **after** the `TableView` is populated (as they can change based on the user's selections elsewhere in the scene).

In the MCVE below, I have two columns for my `Item` class: `Name` and `Color`. Within the `Color` column, I have the `ComboBox` which will display the current value of the Item's `itemColor` property.

You will see that the `ComboBox` is not populated with a list of values yet and item "Three" has no value selected.

**What I need is this:**

When the user clicks on the "Load Available Colors" button, the list for the `ComboBox` is created. The user can now select any of the available colors. However, if there is not already a value for the item's color, I want the first color in the `ComboBoxes` to be selected automatically; so item "Three" would now show the color "Red" as being selected.

> **THE MCVE**

**Item.java:**

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Item {

    private StringProperty itemName = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private StringProperty itemColor = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public Item(String name, String color) {
        this.itemName.set(name);
        this.itemColor.set(color);
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName.get();
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName.set(itemName);
    }

    public StringProperty itemNameProperty() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public String getItemColor() {
        return itemColor.get();
    }

    public void setItemColor(String itemColor) {
        this.itemColor.set(itemColor);
    }

    public StringProperty itemColorProperty() {
        return itemColor;
    }
}
```

**Main.java:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    // List of items
    private static ObservableList<Item> listOfItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    // List of available Colors. These will be selectable from the ComboBox
    private static ObservableList<String> availableColors = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private static void buildSampleData() {

        availableColors.addAll("Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Black");
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple Interface
        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        // Build a list of sample data. This data is loaded from my data model and passed to the constructor
        // of this editor in my real application.
        listOfItems.addAll(
                new Item("One", "Black"),
                new Item("Two", "Black"),
                new Item("Three", null),
                new Item("Four", "Green"),
                new Item("Five", "Red")
        );

        // TableView to display the list of items
        TableView<Item> tableView = new TableView<>();

        // Create the TableColumn
        TableColumn<Item, String> colName = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        TableColumn<Item, String> colColor = new TableColumn<>("Color");

        // Cell Property Factories
        colName.setCellValueFactory(column -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(column.getValue().getItemName()));
        colColor.setCellValueFactory(column -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(column.getValue().getItemColor()));

        // Add ComboBox to the Color column, populated with the list of availableColors
        colColor.setCellFactory(tc -> {
            ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>(availableColors);
            comboBox.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
            TableCell<Item, String> cell = new TableCell<Item, String>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String color, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(color, empty);
                    if (empty) {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    } else {
                        setGraphic(comboBox);
                        comboBox.setValue(color);
                    }
                }
            };

            // Set the action of the ComboBox to set the right Value to the ValuePair
            comboBox.setOnAction(event -> {
                listOfItems.get(cell.getIndex()).setItemColor(comboBox.getValue());
            });

            return cell;
        });

        // Add the column to the TableView
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(colName, colColor);
        tableView.setItems(listOfItems);

        // Add button to load the data
        Button btnLoadData = new Button("Load Available Colors");
        btnLoadData.setOnAction(event -> {
            buildSampleData();
        });
        root.getChildren().add(btnLoadData);

        // Add the TableView to the root layout
        root.getChildren().add(tableView);

        Button btnPrintAll = new Button("Print All");
        btnPrintAll.setOnAction(event -> {
            for (Item item : listOfItems) {
                System.out.println(item.getItemName() + " : " + item.getItemColor());
            }
        });
        root.getChildren().add(btnPrintAll);

        // Show the stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Sample");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

---

Now, with a regular `ComboBox`, a simple call to `comboBox.getSelectionModel().selectFirst()` after loading the `availableColors` would be fine. But since this `ComboBox` is created within the `CellFactory`, I am not sure how to update it once the list of colors is populated.

> Indidentally, I use this `CellFactory` implementation instead of a `ComboBoxTableCell` because I want them to be visible without having to enter edit mode on the `TableView`.

Comment: don't quite understand: you have no null value in the table's items, so the combo will have the selected value always. and the table isn't editable, so selections won't have any effect anyway .. What am I missing? Maybe simply to early on a rainy Monday morning for me :)

Comment: @kleopatra He doesn't specify a `cellValueFactory` so even in non-empty cells the value is ***always*** `null`. @Zephyr Furthermore there is no way to store the info when a different item is selected in the combobox. And the comboboxes could easily be reset e.g. by scrolling the `TableView`. If you fix this what is wrong with initializing the item "properties" to the default value? This way the item values match the values shown in the table.

Comment: @fabian good catch! but then the example is completely rotten ;)

Comment: The example is an MCVE. I do not have questions that affect my data model, so I did not include it. I just have questions on the functionality of the ComboBoxes that are within the cells.

Comment: @fabian - I have updated my question and changed the MCVE to better demonstrate the issue.

Comment: you must not by-pass the edit mechanism! The cell is _not_ the place to implement data logic. Wrong approach ... Instead do it on the data side: if you want each item to have a default color, instantiate it with a default color - when loading the colors, update each item to the first of the list it it's null. Unrelated: no need for all those dirty statics .. not even in an example ;)

Comment: unrelated btw: good that you got rid off the PropertyValueFactory, finally :)) But why do you wrap a new property around the value from the getter? The usual way - if the data class exposes a property - is `setCellValueFactory(cc -> cc.getValue().nameProperty())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually took kleopatra's advice and updated my data model to include a default value instead. I agree this is cleaner and more appropriate approach.